# Process DataReceivedEventArgs event is not triggering

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to add watermark in the video. I am trying to write log on console but I don't know why my `MyEvent` event is not calling.

```
public void ConvertVideo(string path)
        {
            string command = string.Format("-i {0} -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4", Path);
            ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe", command)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
            };

            Process p = new Process();

            void MyEvent(object s, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.Writeline(e.Data);
            }

            try
            {
                p.OutputDataReceived += MyEvent;
                p.StartInfo = oInfo;
                p.Start();
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                p.BeginErrorReadLine();
                p.WaitForExit(10000000);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Writeline(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (p != null)
                {
                    p.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I update the line ```p.OutputDataReceived += MyEvent;``` with ```p.ErrorDataReceived += MyEvent;``` then it will show the result on console

Comment: Instead of just updating your question and adding a comment, you could write an answer yourself with a short explanation. With that, other users would be able to benefit from your post. On the other hand, if you think, the question/answer is not so relevant, as you merely made a small error in your code, you could delete the question and comment altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You first create a new Process object and add the `OutputDataReceived` event. That looks all good but then you overwrite that Process object by calling `Process.Start(oInfo)` which means that the subscription you created for the `OutputDataReceived` event is overwritten.

Instead of doing `p = Process.Start(oInfo)` you could probably just do `p.Start(oInfo)` or `p.StartInfo = oInfo;` and then `p.Start();`. That way the MyEvent subscription is still there when the process is started and the output should be routed properly.

Comment: Not working. Still event is not triggering

Comment: Have you verified that the process starts properly and actually runs? You could also check that the process really runs through and outputs something to the console by not redirecting the output and showing the window instead of hiding it.

Comment: yes, the process is running. even it completing its job.

Comment: Could you update the code to reflect the changes you made based on my suggestions? I'll see if I spot something else that could go wrong there.

Comment: I found something strange. If I update the line ```p.OutputDataReceived += MyEvent;``` with ```p.ErrorDataReceived += MyEvent;``` then it will show the result on console

Comment: Sounds strange. I know that reading the output stream is a bit more involved than immediately obvious because of the possible race conditions and buffer problems if you don't read from them enough. Haven't seen something like that before though.